# Chrome mobile, Navigation is blocked when redirecting to SMS

Tags: android, google-chrome, sms, mobile-chrome

I'm trying to open the SMS outbox when the user lands on a page. It does work on the Android stock browser and 
Firefox, but not on Chrome (it only works if they click on a link).

I'm getting the "Navigation is blocked" error, without any further explanation:

[image: Navigation is blocked]

I've tried with window.location.href, location.href, window.location, with setTimeout... but nothing.

Do you know any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, it seems that Chrome is blocking some request that are called using "window.location" when these calls have variables.

As a workaround, try creating an anchor, set the `href` attribute and click it (programatically).

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('href',desiredLink); //<-- this is the URL
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Comment: I'm trying this with `tel:` instead of `sms:`, however, your answer is not working for me.